# Помогите найти движение товаров между датами

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста как найти движение товаров по дню.

У нас есть сумма на конец дня это Итог за день = 5

Требуется найти движение в промежутках времени, а именно из последнего вычитаем предыдущее, то есть из 5 - 2 = 3, далее из предпоследнего предыдущее ему: 2 - 1 = 1, далее между последними двумя датами: 1 - 2 = -1

```
create table #info
   (
   Date  smalldatetime,
   Brief varchar(20),
   Qty   money
   )
insert into #info
select '2021-09-14 21:36:00', 'Итог по 1', 5 union all
select '2021-09-14 22:36:00', 'Итог по 2', 10 union all
select '2021-09-14 15:25:00', 'Товар',     2 union all
select '2021-09-14 12:47:00', 'Товар',     1 union all
select '2021-09-14 10:22:00', 'Товар',     2 union all
select '2021-09-14 16:27:00', 'Товар2',    5 union all
select '2021-09-14 15:34:00', 'Товар2',    3 union all
select '2021-09-14 12:55:00', 'Товар2',    2
```

Получиться должно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, за день было 3 движения по товару и 3 движения по 2ому товару.

Comment: Вот какой смысл приводить пример данных за ОДИН день, если для расчёта движения нужны данные как минимум за ДВА дня? дополните данные, и приложите к ним требуемый ответ для именно таких данных. PS. Используйте функцию LAG() в CTE. PPS. Что делать, если за какую-то дату нет данных? имеется более 1 записи? не говорите, что такого не бывает - структура таблицы позволяет, а, значит, такое может быть.

Comment: Расчеты нужны в промежутках времени, а не за ДВА дня. Между 2021-09-14 10:22:00 и 2021-09-14 12:47:00, 2021-09-14 12:47:00 и 2021-09-14 15:25:00, 2021-09-14 15:25:00 и 2021-09-14 21:36:00.

Comment: Ну так покажите нужный ответ-то, ё моё... под данными, табличкой...

Comment: Да, загрузил, извиняюсь

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *, Qty - LAG(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY Date) change
FROM #info
ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

или

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, Qty - LAG(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY Date) change
              FROM #info )
SELECT Date,  N'Товар' Brief, change Qty
FROM cte
WHERE change IS NOT NULL;
```

> А данный запрос возможно написать без функции LAG() ? –
> Graund

```sql
SELECT t1.Date, t1.Brief, t1.Qty - t2.Qty change
FROM #info t1
JOIN #info t2 ON t1.Date > t2.Date
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM #info t3
                   WHERE t1.Date > t3.Date
                     AND t3.Date > t2.Date)
```

или

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) rn 
              FROM #info )
SELECT t1.Date, t1.Brief, t1.Qty - t2.Qty change
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn + 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6d6aa25cdf4df2ab432cfdaf6b32994

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: А данный запрос возможно написать без функции LAG() ?

Comment: @Graund Можно. Но запрос получится неэффективный.

Comment: Просто у нас старый сервер 2008(SP2) =(

Comment: @Graund Добавил.

Comment: а если добавляется 2ой товар, то этот запрос уже не валидный правильно же? Подскажи пожалуйста, данные обновил.

Comment: @Graund Тогда просто добавляется ещё одно условие в выражение связывания либо PARTITION BY в определение окна.

Comment: Получилось, ещё раз большое спасибо!)